# Resizing images to a specific width (in cm) while maintainig their aspect ratios

Tags: r

I have a folder with a large number of images of different sizes. However, I want to resize all of them so that they are 23.6cm wide, but maintain their respective aspect ratios.

I couldn't figure out how to resize the images based on cms. This is what I tried so far:

```
library(magick)

original_images <- list.files('Data/input/Images')

for(image in original_images){
  print(image)
  fp <- paste0('Data/input/Images/', image)
  og <- image_read(fp)
  new <- image_resize(og, "643x") # this is in pixels I think?
  image_write(new, path = paste0('Data/output/Images/', image), density = 300)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one approach:

```
## how many inches are 23.6 cm?
w_inches = 23.6 / grDevices::cm(1)
## > w_inches
## [1] 9.291339


## how many pixels do we need at 300 dpi?
w_pixels = w_inch * 300
## > w_pixels
## [1] 2787.402

## resize:
og |> image_resize(paste0(w_pixels, 'x'))
```